# navbar bootstrap does not collapse mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, width, navbar

I have a problem with my bootstrap navbar on a site www.eefjerotterdam.nl/nieuw.

The navbar collapses on desktop when I resize my browser to mobile width. But when I load it in a mobile browser it does not seem to work for some reason. It does collapse, but it keeps a width that is way to wide. I've tried answers on similar questions like the viewport meta etc.

The rest of the page does resize, it's just the navbar that keeps insane width on mobile. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRfb8.jpg)

Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have 1380px owl carousel. Thats causing the huge width of page. Make it responsive so the issue will be solved.

```
<div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 1380px; left: 0px; display: block;">
...
</div>
```

Change your this part on your custom.js file

```
$('.intro-slider').owlCarousel({
        paginationSpeed: 600,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: false,
        singleItem: true,
        slideSpeed: 600,
        autoPlay: 3000
    });
```

You can find the owl carousel responsive configuration there:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html

Comment: Please mark it as an answer to benefit other people asking the same question.